# React Native - Android issue with WebView scroll

Tags: react-native

WebView scroll is not working in Android. I have searched a lot and seen a lot of other places, no one was able to help.

This is how I defined the component

```
 <WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{uri: this.props.url}}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    decelerationRate="normal"
    startInLoadingState={true}
    scalesPageToFit={isAndroid ? false : true}
/>
```

This seems a react native bug (which is out there forever), but there should be a workaround.

-- **UPDATE** --

I figured out that this is not the WebView problem and it's happening because I have it in a Modal and `TouchableWithoutFeedback` is needed to hide the modal and of course not hide when they touch inside the modal.
`TouchableWithoutFeedback` steals the press event and does not the scroll work.

```
<Modal
    animationType='fade'
    onRequestClose={() => { }}
    transparent
    visible={visible} //its either true or false, if its ture it will be displayed if false, it will hide
>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onDecline} >
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            <Ionicons name="md-close" size={24} color={colors.primary} style={closeIconStyle} />
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { }} >
                <View style={popupStyle}>
                    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                        <Text style={textStyle}>
                            {this.props.title}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[cardSectionStyle, {
                        marginTop: 5
                    }]}>

                        <View style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 300, width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 80 }}>
                            <WebView
                                source={{ uri: this.props.url }}
                                style={contentStyle}
                                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                                domStorageEnabled={true}
                                decelerationRate="normal"
                                startInLoadingState={true}
                            />

                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Modal>
```

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `style={flex: 1}` in the `<Webview />` tag.

If it's still not working, just try this:

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: this.props.url }}
    style={{marginTop: 20, flex: 1}}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding "nestedScrollEnabled" property in WebView worked for me